# Arguments for "launch configuration" while building JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm building a runnable JAR from my Eclipse project, and while exporting it as a runnable JAR, Eclipse is prompting me to provide a *launch configuration*.

My question is If i give some arguments like

> java -jar test.jar import.txt export.txt" while running this jar

will it override the arguments from launch config given while exporting.

Comment: Not sure, but you definitely need to mention which IDE you're using.  Launch config is not a global concept :)

Comment: What do you mean by "exporting"?

Comment: By exporting the project as runnable jar in Eclipse@C.Champagne

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx Its Eclipse. While exporting as runnable jar

Comment: what is the config you are giving during export ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just need to mention your startup class, the one having the `public static main(String[] args)` method.